# Toggling between two bootstrap modals not working

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am working on login/account creation in django and I am trying to use modals so users can create one of two accounts. I have been basing my design off of bootstrap's ['Toggle between modals' example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/#toggle-between-modals).

Yet I cannot seem to get it to work completely. I get it to toggle once correctly, but then it gets messed up during consecutive switches between the two. If anyone knows what is going on, that would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code for reference:

```
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <a role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mt-3" data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#createCoach">
        Create an account
    </a>

    <!-- Coach Creation Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="createCoach" tabindex="-1"  aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="modalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#createCoach" disabled>
                            Create Coach Account
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#createAthlete">
                            Create Athlete Account
                        </button>
                    </h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{coach_creation_form|crispy}}
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="1" name="create-coach">Create coach account</button>
                </div>
                    </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Athlete Creation Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="createAthlete" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="modalLabel2">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel2">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#createCoach">
                            Create Coach Account
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#createAthlete" disabled>
                            Create Athlete Account
                        </button>
                    </h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{athlete_create_form|crispy}}
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="1" name="create-athlete">Create athlete account</button>
                </div>
                    </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and it works fine for me. One thing I noticed is that your closing `</form>` tag is outside of the **modal-body**. Can you please clarify what gets "messed up during consecutive switches between the two".